# Using Haskell's HDBC, can I use a single SQLite connection across multiple threads?

Tags: database, sqlite, haskell, concurrency, hdbc

If I want to query (read) from an SQLite database using Haskell's HDBC across multiple threads, can I use a single connection, or should each thread have its own connection? Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest using clone as described under http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HDBC/2.3.1.2/doc/html/Database-HDBC.html to make sure that the driver doesn't mess up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched through the hdbc-sqlite code and found this [comment](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HDBC-sqlite3/2.3.3.0/doc/html/src/Database-HDBC-Sqlite3-Statement.html):

> Logic for handling counts of changes: look at the total changes before
>   and after the query.  If they differ, then look at the local changes. 
>   (The local change counter appears to not be updated unless really
>   running a query that makes a change, according to the docs.)
>
> This is OK thread-wise because SQLite doesn't support using a given
>   dbh in more than one thread anyway.

The official Sqlite documentation has a whole page about this [topic](http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html)

The [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) says:

> (5) Can multiple applications or multiple instances of the same
>   application access a single database file at the same time?
>
> Multiple processes can have the same database open at the same time.
>   Multiple processes can be doing a SELECT at the same time. But only
>   one process can be making changes to the database at any moment in
>   time, however.

This information would exclude both of your approaches. Perhaps you can write some tests for this to show that this information are wrong.